# Can I use an automated model selection approach on an lmer object?

Tags: r, mixed-model, model-selection, lme4-nlme

I am attempting to use `MuMIn` to run a model selection analysis on a mixed model fitted using `lme4`.

Because this model is fit using restricted maximum likelihood (REML), I am confused as to whether I can use an automated model selection approach such as that implemented in `MuMIn`.  This is because `MuMIn` ranks models using AICc and maximum likelihood (ML), and thus the weights of any candidate models obtained are ML based.

Does anyone know if this is a problem? If it is a problem, are there any other model selection packages in R that are more compatible?

Comment: I find this page very helpful whenever I deal with the lme4 package (http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq) They have a section on calculating AIC for GLMMs. It might be helpful to read some of the papers they cite.

Comment: As my econometrics instructor used to say, "This is a free country [USA -- StasK], you can do whatever you want. The *real* question is, can you defend it, and can you publish it?". AIC assumes i.i.d. data, which is clearly violated with `lmer`-type mixed models. Different parameters have different information content, and it is difficult to quantify properly when you have random slopes.